# Saving parquet in Spark as non root user

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, parquet

I am running pyspark as a non root user and try to save a dataframe as parquet.

My Environment:

- Ubuntu 14
- Spark 1.4.1 prebuild for Hadoop 2.6
- GlusterFS 3.7
- Mesos 0.23.0
- Docker 1.7.1

Start *pyspark* as e.g. *user1* and load some data into a dataframe `df`. Then run `df.write.format("parquet").save("/data/user1/wikipedia_test.parquet")`

`/data` is a GlusterFS voulme on each node.
`/data/user1` permissions:

```
# owner: user1
# group: user1
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::---
default:user::rwx
default:group::r-x
default:other::---
```

After spark is done with the computation and all results are stored in temporary files, the task failes:

```
java.io.IOException: 
Failed to rename DeprecatedRawLocalFileStatus{
  path=file:/data/user1/wikipedia_test.parquet/_temporary/0/task_201507312025_0004_m_000024/part-r-00024-215e6e02-553e-434f-a2ae-e46836d39274.gz.parquet; 
  isDirectory=false; 
  length=2081649; 
  replication=1; 
  blocksize=33554432; 
  modification_time=1438374352000; 
  access_time=0; 
  owner=; 
  group=; 
  permission=rw-rw-rw-; 
  isSymlink=false
} 
to file:/data/user1/wikipedia_test.parquet/part-r-00024-215e6e02-553e-434f-a2ae-e46836d39274.gz.parquet
```

The problem is that the temporary files are created by root and the driver is not allowed to rename these files to their final destination.

```
user1@host:/data/user1/wikipedia_test.parquet/_temporary/0/task_201507312105_0006_m_000000$ ll
total 2741
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root     169 Jul 31 21:05 ./
drwxr-xr-x 62 root root   20480 Jul 31 21:06 ../
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 2763432 Jul 31 21:05 part-r-00000-bbb1e377-5294-450c-9b87-648b68ec80c5.gz.parquet
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   21600 Jul 31 21:05 .part-r-00000-bbb1e377-5294-450c-9b87-648b68ec80c5.gz.parquet.crc
```

Tomasz described a workaround in https://www.mail-archive.com/user@spark.apache.org/msg28820.html which works but is not applicable for us.
Because we need a real permission system where users are not allowed to write into other users folders.

Additionaly setting `$SPARK_USER` to either `root` or `user1` has no effekt.
By the way doing the same while running pyspark as root works.

I think the main problem is that Spark-slaves are always executed as root.

Any ideas?

Comment: just in case, spark master should not be running as root, but rather as another user. let's say, "spark". or "yarn" in case of hadoop. feel free to update the issue with your findings :)

Comment: @nefo_x bingo! Worked for me. I had same problem when I had started Spark as root, it was creating parquet files with a variety of owners - user and root. Running Spark as user calmed down that strange behavior and Parquet overwrites are working now.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the uid of 'user1' on every node in your cluster. You can do this with the 'id' command when logged in as that user. If the different machines use different uids for the same user then you might get this write permissions error.

This can happen if user1 (uid 12345) on one machine creates the output folders, which user1 (uid 24680) on another machine doesn't then have write access to.